# The RIGHT() function in PostgreSQL gives an error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use the `RIGHT()` function it so it will only display the last 4 digits of a credit card number pulled from the customer table. This is what I have so far:

```
create function get_customer(text) returns setof cusinfo as

$$

select upper(first_name)||' '||upper(last_name) as full_name, upper(address), upper(city)||', '||upper(state)||' '||zip as citystatezip, email, '************'||right(cc_number,4), cc_name

from customer

where customer_id = $1;

$$ language sql;
```

The error I am being given is:

> psql:finalproject.sql:273: ERROR:  function right(text, integer) does not exist
>       LINE 3: ...|' '||zip as citystatezip, email, '************'||right(cc_n...

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I tried only using `RIGHT()` by itself and putting in something like `RIGHT('Help me', 2)`, but I get the same error.

Comment: Never used Postgres, but Google told me this: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?366698-is-there-a-RIGHT-function-in-postgres

Comment: [Pgsql doesn't list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html) `RIGHT() / LEFT()` string functions

Comment: You're storing the credit card number in plaintext?

Comment: @p.campbell I bet the frontend is PHP.

Comment: @ta.speot.is The only keywords given by the OP here are `psql`.  Doesn't matter the layer above; this error is being thrown by the RDBMS in a function.

Comment: @p.campbell I was just completing the technology stack. CC in plaintext and all deserves to be served up via PHP...

Comment: Sorry about the lack of proper tags. We are using a website that was designed by our professor to allow us to test our abilities with psql. I wasn't sure what the proper tags would be. I'm still very new to this site, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I can't speculate on whether the calling layer is PHP or JSP or ASP.NET or Django.

Comment: Charlie: no worries on the tagging. The client layer doesn't matter.

Comment: The server version *does* matter, though. There is a `right(text, int)` function in PostgreSQL starting with version 9.1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER The docs cited in an earlier comment were for version 8.1, which has been out of support for almost two years now.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming `psql` is PostgreSQL. If that's the case, you should read the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html) describing the string functions that are available to you.

`right` is not one of them.

Try `substring(cc_number from char_length(cc_number) - 3)`.

In future you may want to use Google to help answer questions like this. Google is a search engine; you can use search engines to find documentation; documentation tells you how to use a product.

Comment: That did it. I thought that it would have been the same function regardless of which flavor of sql. And yes, I am using psql. Thank you very much. Oh, one last thing, for whatever reason, it displayed the last 5 digits when I did -4. I changed it to -3 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Voting up for the answer because it was helpful, but I think the question was good. This SO post was easier to find than the page in the documentation.

Comment: No longer relevant - see answer below

Answer (score 4):

RIGHT(str, num) - was added to Postgresql in version 9.1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create the missing RIGHT function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS
    RIGHT
        (
            IN_STRING VARCHAR(4000),
            RIGHT_OFFSET INT
        );

CREATE FUNCTION
    RIGHT
        (
            IN_STRING VARCHAR(4000),
            RIGHT_OFFSET INT
        )
    RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    BEGIN 
        RETURN SUBSTRING(IN_STRING FROM CHAR_LENGTH(IN_STRING) - (RIGHT_OFFSET - 1));
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Adapted from @ta.speot.is's answer.